# How can an electric dryer be so "efficient" compared to a dryer rack?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, water, evaporation

I wash my clothes, and when they get off the washer, its weight was increased by 3.35kg (amount of water to be evaporated to get dry clothes).

Now, I have two options:

- Use an **electric dryer**. It takes 2 hours to dry the clothes, it's a 2700W dryer, so I used **5.4kWh**.
- Use a **dryer rack**. Then, water is evaporated by [latent heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_heat). I washed at 40°C, so the 3.35kg of water to be evaporated is probably at 35°C. Considering [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_heat#Specific_latent_heat_for_condensation_of_water_-_in_clouds), I need `2500-2,36*35+0,0016*35*35-0,00006*35*35*35`, which is 2416kj/kg to evaporate the water, so, according to [google converted](https://www.google.fr/search?q=convert%20kJ%20to%20Watt#q=kj%20en%20wh), this is 0.617kWH/kg, so **2.07kWh**.

I'm really surprised an electric dryer only consumes twice the energy needed to naturally evaporate the water. If my room heater works with fuel or gas, the 2.07kWh consumed to dry the clothes on the rack may end up emitting more carbon than the electric dryer would (if the electricity is produced cleanly).

This result really surprises me (I would have expected the electric dryer to consume at least 10 times more than natural evaporation). It makes me believe that I did something wrong in my computation...did I?

Comment: How much energy is consumed at the power company to deliver the 5.4 kWh of electricity to your home?

Comment: @ChesterMiller: And to deliver the fuel I burn in my heater? ;-)

Comment: Why would you think that your electric dryer needs so much input energy to dry the clothes? Using a dryer rack or simply hanging the clothes outside on a clothes line requires you to provide 0 watts of additional energy. Seems that you're assuming that the electric dryer has to actually elevate the temperature of all the water in the clothes to 100 C and also in addition supply the latent heat to transform all that liquid water into steam in order to dry clothes, but that's not what it does.

Comment: @SamuelWeir: `Why would you think that your electric dryer needs so much input energy to dry the clothes?` 2 hours at 2700W is definitely 5.4kWh...

Comment: @SamuelWeir: I assume the dryer rack consumes some energy at some point, so, in winter, I have to compensate this energy consumed through my room heater, else, the temperature will dicrease. That's what I'm assuming and trying to evaluate how much energy is consumed by this natural evaporation. But I can be wrong...

Comment: Look, heat is everywhere around you. You don't need to supply umpteen kWh of energy to evaporate a pot of water. You can just leave it on the stove or put it outside on a warm day and the ambient temperature will help evaporate the water for you. It's only if you're in a hurry that you need to supply additional heat to speed things along. That's what a clothes dryer does. Its intention is not to heat all that water in the clothes up to 100 C and beyond. Its intention is simply to get the clothes warm enough that with a good flow of air the rate of evaporation is accelerated.

Comment: Using the drying rack isn't really taking heat out of your home.  The water vapor from the cloths may well condense somewhere else (cooler) and presto you get your heat back.

Comment: @jpo38 and other commentators: Simple event of drying clothes taken to highest level (perhaps) of physics. A salute to all! You people surely have time and patience to think so minutely even in such simple events.........

Comment: @WrichikBasu  Do you mean:  "To those about to dry, we salute you."

Comment: This is follow up to your previous answer to me.  I thought you were talking about an electric dryer, not one that burns fuel.  If it is a dryer that burns fuel, how much energy do you think the oil company consumes producing and refining the fuel?

Comment: @Chester Yes, something of that kind. 

Comment: @M.Enns: My asumption is that the 2.07kWh "consumed" by the dryer rack to evaporate the water may reduce the temperature of my romm in winter, so I would need to compensate that by burning some fuel in my room heater to maintain the expected air temperature. But that could be were I was wrong. If so, could you elaborate where this "energy" is picked from and confirm it does not necessarily reduce the air temperature?

Comment: @M.Enns: Maybe my question should have been "Does my room heater need to compensate the energy consumed by the dryer rack to evaporate the water of my clothes?". If not, it makes sense to say it's better not to use an electric dryer which consumes a lot of electricity, else, it's questionable....